# Is there any way to give a tag or nickname to a process so it can be killed invoking kill <tag>?

Tags: server, ssh, process, git

I have one Ubuntu 12.04 vps and I use git to upload code for a web server, when I push by git to vps I have to login via ssh to vps and look for the process by:

```
ps -A | grep node
```

I kill it once I recognize the `PID` and restart the server.

As git executes some `post-receive` script in order to do the repository changes to the correct location at vps I thought I could add some server **`restart`** or **`stop/start`** instructions, however I think this would be easier having a tag/nickname for the server process as long as I'm not adding any server process as daemon.

What solution is it suggested?

Answer (score 1):

You could automate your current method with `pidof`:

```
kill -HUP `pidof node`
```

In bash, using backticks (``) runs the command inside the backticks first, and puts the output of that command into the command on the outside (the `kill -HUP`). Handy one to know.

Comment: Very useful! What does -HUP arguments stand for?
The issue in this case is that there can be more than 1 node instance running

Comment: I've never actually run node.js, so I'm assuming that node processes respond to a HUP signal (most daemons respond to a HUP by restarting).

Comment: So `-HUP` makes the process restart?

Comment: Not necessarily. How a HUP signal is handled depends on the process receiving the signal. It's convention for a bunch of services (like Apache) to reload their config and gracefully restart on receiving a HUP signal, but that's not universal.

Comment: I get it, thanks.I will check for it, if I could have a such *tag* I'd add it to your suggestion and it would work.

A definitive workaround is to obtain the PID and store it somewhere once the node process is lanuched, then look for that stored PID and do the kill.

Like:

kill -HUP \`grab stored PID\`